# How to globally disable minification in Minify

Tags: compression, minify

I'm using Minify - http://code.google.com/p/minify/ to combine my .js files into one but Minify is also minifying/compressing the JavaScript files as well and I don't want that. I know there is a debug mode, but I don't want that either, I just one to globally configure Minify just to combine the specified files/groups in groupsConfig.php, nothing more.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In Version 2.5.1 you can put this in the config.php:

```
$min_serveOptions['minApp']['noMinPattern'] = '#\.(?:js|css)$#i';
```

This means all files ending with js or css won't be minified.
This option is used normaly to avoid the minifying of allready compressed files like '*.min.js' or smilar.

Answer (score 1):

[If you'd like to temporarily disable the cache without using debug mode, place these settings at the end of config.php:](https://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/CommonProblems)

```
// disable server caching
$min_cachePath = null;
// prevent client caching
$min_serveOptions['maxAge'] = 0;
$min_serveOptions['lastModifiedTime'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```